# Spring Boot Loads Before Embedded Cassandra When Using Cucumber, How Can I Fix This?

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra, cucumber

I am having some issues using spring-cassandra-unit, spring-boot, and spring-cucumber. The below configuration works fine for unit tests, but as soon as I add spring-cucumber into the mix and attempt some integration tests, it appears that it flat out ignores my MyCustomOrderedTestExecutionListener and loads spring boot before cassandra, giving me a "NoHostFoundException".

I really could use advice on how to ensure embedded cassandra is loaded first. Any help is greatly appreciated.

The following setup:

```
@ActiveProfile("INTEGRATION_TEST")
@SpringBootTest
@EmbeddedCassandra(configuration = "cassandra.yaml")
@TestExecutionListeners(
  listeners = MyCustomOrderedTestExecutionListener.class,
  mergeMode = MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS)
@CassandraDataSet(value = "cql/dataset1.cql", keyspace = "mykeyspace")
public class TestStepDef{

//omitted for brevity

}
```

My Custom ordered test execution listener:

```
public class MyCustomOrderedTestExecutionListener extends AbstractTestExecutionListener {

    @Override
    public void afterTestMethod(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
       //omitted for brevity
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return  Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE;
    }
}
```

Cucumber Test Runner:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="resources/features", glue="resources/glue")
public class TestRunner {}
```

Edit:

Looking at cucumber spring's spring factory, the app context is loaded even before beforeTestClass is executed (beforeTestClass is executed by notifyContextManagerAboutTestClassStarted):

```
 public void start() {
        if (this.stepClassWithSpringContext != null) {
            this.testContextManager = new CucumberTestContextManager(this.stepClassWithSpringContext);  
        } else if (this.beanFactory == null) {
            this.beanFactory = this.createFallbackContext();
        }

        this.notifyContextManagerAboutTestClassStarted();
        if (this.beanFactory == null || this.isNewContextCreated()) {
            this.beanFactory = this.testContextManager.getBeanFactory();
            Iterator var1 = this.stepClasses.iterator();

            while(var1.hasNext()) {
                Class<?> stepClass = (Class)var1.next();
                this.registerStepClassBeanDefinition(this.beanFactory, stepClass);
            }
        }

        GlueCodeContext.INSTANCE.start();
    }
```

Going deeper we can see the app context is loaded here:

```
class CucumberTestContextManager extends TestContextManager {
    public CucumberTestContextManager(Class<?> testClass) {
        super(testClass);
        this.registerGlueCodeScope(this.getContext());
    }

     private ConfigurableApplicationContext getContext() {
    return (ConfigurableApplicationContext)this.getTestContext().getApplicationContext();
     }
...

}
```

Any advice on how to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Cucumber only invokes `TestContextManager.beforeClass` and `TestContextManager.afterClass`. However this happens before every scenario so overriding `TestExecutionListener.afterTestClass` should do the trick.

Comment: @CoffeeIsProgramming what should I be looking at? After method and after class are two different hooks. You're not also looking at the before class, yet another hook.

Comment: Sorry should have been more specific. I am looking at the Cassandra Spring source code. My point is that I need Embedded Cassandra to load before Spring Boot. Spring is immediately trying to connect to Cassandra when it boots and if it boots first there is nothing for it to connect to. In version 1.2.5 of cucumber-spring, TestExecutionListener.afterTestClass won't be called until well after the application context is loaded.In fact TestExecutionListener.beforeTestClass won't either. 

I will check beforeTest, I haven't checked that yet...

Comment: Cucumber doesnt call before test IIRC.

Comment: Prolly best send a PR to Cucumber to fix it.

Comment: Thanks will do. Aside from attempting a patch myself that’s the most I can do.

Comment: Going to give you the answer on this one. You were able to help point me in the right direction and give me advice on which hooks I should be looking at.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

**IntegrationConfig:**

```
class IntegrationConfiguration {
// your cassandra startup
}
```

**ComponentTestSpecification**:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@Import(IntegrationConfiguration.class)
abstract class ComponentTestSpecification {
// reusable integration-test methods here
}
```

**The Test (groovy, should be convertable to jUnit / whatever):**

```
class AccessControllerSpec extends ComponentTestSpecification {
// test methods
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via https://github.com/nosan/embedded-cassandra project

```java
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;

import com.github.nosan.embedded.cassandra.test.spring.EmbeddedCassandra;

@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("INTEGRATION_TEST")
@EmbeddedCassandra(configurationFile = "cassandra.yaml", scripts = "cql/dataset1.cql")
public class TestStepDef {


}
```

`@EmbeddedCassandra` is handled by `org.springframework.test.context.ContextCustomizer` thus you will not have any issues with a startup.